# Restricting user input as HHMMSS

Tags: java, date-formatting

I am trying to calculate the angle of the hour-minute, hour-second, second-minute hand of clock. I figure out the calculation but I am having trouble with formatting user input. 
This is what I want to get...

Input time: 235429

Second-hour: 176.76 degrees
Minute-second: 152.9 degrees
Hour-minute: 30.34 degrees

As you can see, I would like to have format of user input as HHMMSS, but I have no idea how to format it. Can you guys give me any idea how to format the user input that it can detect each two individual characters like HH, MM, and SS? T
Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: have you seen the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Use Java 8 [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) with a [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) using pattern `"HHmmss"` passed to [`parse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-).

*Example*

```
String userInput = "235429";

LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(userInput, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HHmmss"));
System.out.println("Hour  : " + time.getHour());
System.out.println("Minute: " + time.getMinute());
System.out.println("Second: " + time.getSecond());
```

*Output*

```
Hour  : 23
Minute: 54
Second: 29
```

If user gives bad input, e.g. `236429`, it throws exception:

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '236429' could not be parsed: Invalid value for MinuteOfHour (valid values 0 - 59): 64

Trap the exception to detect and handle invalid input from the user.

```
try {
    LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(userInput, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HHmmss"));
} catch (DateTimeParseException e){
    …  // Handle invalid user’s invalid input.
}
```

Comment: Is there anyway that I can combine 3 inputs into one input? Like Input= HHMMSS;

Comment: @HyunMoLukeYang `235429` *is* 3 values (hour, minute, and second) combined into one in the format `HHMMSS`. I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Oh what i mean is that Instead of listing 3 different inputs like                 
Hour  : 23
Minute: 54
Second: 29

Comment: @HyunMoLukeYang I'm so not following you, *at all*. Question says that you have/want input in the form of `HHMMSS`, and that you need to do some calculations where you need the hour, minute, and second values from that input. This answer illustrates how to get hour, minute, and second from the input string. Isn't that what the question was about? If not, maybe you should edit the question and clarify exactly what you need.

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention using Scanner... OMG. My bad I am so sorry. I am trying to use Scanner to put input on running program. Will that change into totally different solution?

Comment: @HyunMoLukeYang No. Using `Scanner` to read the 6-character input text is fine and has nothing to do with *parsing* the input into hour, minute and second.

Comment: So for clarification, I am trying to use Scanner and I would like to format the Scanner input like "HHMMSS". Is there a way that I can range and restrict input of Scanner?

Comment: @HyunMoLukeYang No. You read the input from user, and if user enters the wrong thing, you print a message saying so, and ask the user to try again. In this case, you detect that user entered the wrong thing by catching the exception.